# [Theorical] Qt-ros package for ROS Melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to  migrate a project from ROS Kinetic to ROS Melodic. I've developed an application GUI to control a robot, but when I try to install the dependencies for this project in ROS Melodic, the console output tells me that qt-build package is still not developed for this ROS distro. 1) Does anyone know if there's a way to install this packages in ROS Melodic?

In case this option is not allowed, 2) how can I migrate qt user interface into ROS Melodic using qt ros pluggin?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346339/%5Btheorical%5D-qt-ros-package-for-ros-melodic/) by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2020-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eberty](https://answers.ros.org/users/52373/eberty/) on 2020-03-10**:
Please, see: https://answers.ros.org/question/337030/qt-5-for-ros-melodic/

**Comment by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on 2020-03-11**:
Thanks, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have create this template for ROS Melodic and Qt. Hope that will help.
https://github.com/alexspirou/ROS_Melodic_Qt_GUI_Template

---

Originally posted by [alexspi13](https://answers.ros.org/users/57492/alexspi13/) with karma: 36 on 2021-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on 2021-03-23**:
Thank you very much! I have a look to the package and it seems amazing! I'm sure it will be useful to everyone

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you @Eberty, your comment solved my problem! In order to sum up:

1. `qt_build` has no compatibility with ROS Melodic.
2. This post [[1](https://answers.ros.org/question/337030/qt-5-for-ros-melodic/)] shows how to migrate a ROS Kinetic Qt interface into ROS Melodic.

---

Originally posted by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) with karma: 59 on 2020-03-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1